# Finite set has no limit points

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I just want to make sure this argument is not incomplete.

I'm following Baby Rudin, and I managed to prove that for a limit point $p$ of $E$, every neighborhood contains infinitely many points of $E$. So if $S$ is finite, and $y$ is a limit point of $S$, any neighborhood $N$ of $y$ must contain infinitely many points of $S$ -- but $S$ has only finitely many points, so this is impossible, hence no $y$ can be a limit point of $S$.

Most of the arguments Iv'e seen for this corollary are far more involved. Is there a hole in this argument?

Comment: Do you mean any neighborhood of a *limit point* of $E$ must contain infinitely many points of $E$? Otherwise it fails for isolated points of $E$, by definition.

Comment: I've misstated the theorem. Sorry about that. I corrected it -- any limit point of $E$, yes. Is the result correct now?

Comment: After reading the first paragraph of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point), I think that your analysis is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly $a$ is limit point of set $X$ if every interval of $a$ contains at least one point from set $X$ is another definition of limit point.